# Higher order derivative of negative power of cosine function

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, probability-distributions

This is a question I encountered in my own research on Generalized
Hyperbolic Secant (GHS) distributions. It is known that the Laplace transform of the
basis measure for this family is 
$$L\left(  \theta\right)  =\left(  \cos
\theta\right)  ^{-\sigma}$$ where $\sigma >0$ is the scale parameter and $\vert \theta \vert < \pi/2$.

Now I need to compute $L^{\left(  n\right)
}\left(  0\right)  =\left.  \frac{d^{n}}{d\theta^{n}}L\left(  \theta\right)
\right\vert _{\theta=0}$, i.e., the $n$th derivative of $L\left(
\theta\right)  $ at $0$ for each even $n$. Note that $L\left(  \theta\right)
$ is the Laplace transform of a density $f$ that is symmetric around $0$ and
$$
L^{\left(  n\right)  }\left(  0\right)  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n}f\left(
x\right)  dx.
$$
We know $L^{\left(  n\right)  }\left(  0\right)  =0$ if $n$ is odd.

Since
$\cos^{\left(  j\right)  }\left(  0\right)  =0$ whenever $j$ is odd, in
Faa di Bruno's formula for $L^{\left(  n\right)  }\left(  0\right)  $ as
long as $\cos^{\left(  j\right)  }\left(  \theta\right)  $ with $j$ odd
appears, the corresponding summand is $0$. But I was not able to single out
the nonzero terms from this formula.

I also tried induction on $L^{\left(  n\right)  }\left(
0\right)  $ with $n$ even but did not find a pattern yet. (Also tried integration by parts, but computing the primitive $G$ of $f$ and the primitive of $G$ is much involved; also tried to directly compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n+2}f\left(
x\right)  dx$ with $n$ even using contour integral (involving Gamma functions) but failed)

Any suggestions? Thank you.

**Updates**: found this paper "The Curious History of Faa di Bruno's Formula" by Warren P. Johnson. Its page 222 provides Faa di Bruno's determinant formula, a beautiful formua that at least provides a rather complicated recursion for $n$ even.

For the composite function considered here, the diagonals in the upper left triangle of this matrix alternate between being zero and none-zero, which simplies the computation a lot but still is quite messy.

**Update 12/11/2017**: In compliance with a reply in the comment (whose user name I am able to decipher), Theorem 2 and Theorem 3 of the paper "Natural Exponential Families with Quadratic Variance Functions" by Carl N. Morris in 1982 gives the same type of formula for computing this. (QED)

Comment: Some information about the triangle of numbers$$\begin{array}{rl}L(0)&=1\\L^{(2)}(0)/\sigma&=2+3\sigma,\\L^{(4)}(0)/\sigma&=16+30\sigma+15\sigma^2,\\L^{(6)}(0)/\sigma&=272+588\sigma+420\sigma^2+105\sigma^3,\\
\cdots
\end{array}$$can be found at the OEIS [A085734](http://oeis.org/A085734) page

Comment: Thank you. If you know an analytic strategy instead of computing case by case, could you please point me to it? I do not get how triangular numbers come into play yet.

Comment: Just look at the link - there seems to be a (more or less) explicit formula:$$L^{(2n)}(0)=\sum_{m=1}^nT_{n,m}\sigma^m$$with$$T_{n,m}=(-1)^{n+m}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\frac{S1(k, m)}{2^{k-1}k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{2k}{k-j}j^{2n}$$where $S1(k,m)$ are the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: ***Now I need to compute $L^{(n)}(0)$.*** What is the exact meaning of the verb "to compute" in this sentence?

Comment: @fedja: say, what is it when n is 10, 100 or 100000?

Comment: A polynomial in $\sigma$ with rational coefficients of the corresponding degree. What I mean is that there are at least three possible meanings of the request to "compute": looking for an exact algebraic formula (like the above) from which you cannot even figure out whether it is positive or negative without some deep thinking, looking for asymptotics for large $n$ in some regimes, which allows you to answer the sign and size questions, but is useless for algebraic properties, and looking for a stable efficient algorithm that allows you to compute the value. Which one is of interest for you?

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood you. I want the first one, an exact algebraic formula. Your comments point out that asymptotics for large n would be useful too, which I would like to learn about.